# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0), when requesting data! the code works for a while then it breaks

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, geocoding, jsondecoder

I am trying to request geocoding data from the census bureau. The code runs and got more than 1450 records so far (my total is about 60K records), but then it breaks and returns this error :

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

My data looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlVCa.jpg)

Here is my function:

```py
def get_fips(df):  
    
    num=len(ven_lst)
    for i,e in df.itertuples(index=False):
        if e not in repostory_lst:
            try:
                num+=1
                address=i
                vendor=e
                link="https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/onelineaddress?address={0}&benchmark=Public_AR_Census2020&vintage=Census2020_Census2020&layers=10&format=json".format(address)
                reponse = requests.get(link).text
                reponse_1=json.loads(response)
                x=reponse_1['result']['addressMatches'][0]['geographies']['Census Blocks'][0]['GEOID'][:11]

                fields=[num,e,x]
                with open(r'fibs&ven.csv', 'a',newline='') as f: #because my data is big a save all the #data into this csv incase the code breaks
                    writer = csv.writer(f)
                    writer.writerow(fields)
            except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError,IndexError):
                pass
        elif e in repostory_lst:
            pass
    #df_result=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Vendor Code','fips'],index=range(len(fips_lst)))
    #df_result['Vendor Code']=ven_lst
    #df_result['fips']=fips_lst
    #x.to_csv('fibs&ven.csv', mode='a', header=False)
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally if the API on the server side is well written and you have specified format=JSON, it should strictly return JSON data only.
But as a fail safe you should add a header to your get a json response.

Also instead of `text` you can use `json()` and you need not to do `json.loads`

Request like

```
 headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
 reponse_1 = requests.get(link, headers=headers).json()
 # reponse_1=json.loads(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

it turns out the issue was that some of the addresses were PO BOXes, once I had them removed the code worked as expected,

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had an `DecimalField`.
My error was 500

I changed it to `IntegerField`, and I got 200 OK

From

```
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
```

To

```
price = models.IntegerField()
```